# How do I get this figure to appear at the top of a page (using Quarto and R)?

Tags: r, gtsummary, quarto

I am a medical researcher and trying to create a pdf with a summary table in it. To do this, I am using Quarto and the `gtsummary` package. I want the table to appear at the top of a page so it is not split across two pages. It isn't working and I don't know why. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? The table itself is being created correctly, it is just sitting across two pages.

It is not leading to error messages, the table is simply being created where the code chunk is rather than rendering at the top of the next page. I am stumped.

I am reading in an excel file (it is read in correctly). I am running R 4.2.1 and `gtsummary` 1.6.2 on a M1 Macbook Air.

The misbehaving code chunk is below:

```
    #| echo: false
    #| warning: false
    #| fig-dpi: 300
    #| fig-format: jpeg
    #| fig-pos: 't'
    
    theme_gtsummary_journal(journal = 'lancet', set_theme = TRUE)
    
    demo_raw %>% 
      select(-c(patient_id,
                pathogenic_factor,
                adm_date,
                dc_date_time,
                ventilator)) %>% 
      tbl_summary(by = ards_type,
                  label = list(gender ~ 'Gender',
                               age_years ~ 'Age (years)',
                               height_cm ~ 'Height (cm)',
                               weight_kg ~ 'Weight (kg)',
                               ards_risk_factor ~ 'Risk factor',
                               adm_location ~ 'Admitting location',
                               los_days ~ 'Length of stay (days)',
                               apache_ii ~ 'Apache II score',
                               total_proning_sessions ~ 'Proning sessions',
                               outcome ~ 'Outcome'),
                  missing = 'no',
                  statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") %>% 
      bold_labels() %>% 
      modify_caption('**Table 1. Patient Characteristics**')
```

Comment: So you do want the table at the top of next page of where the code chunk is?

Comment: That is what I want. Most importantly, I don't want to the table to be split across two pages.